# Node.js app with express-handlebars in Electron.io

Tags: node.js, electron

I've built express app with express-handlebars templating engine and it all works fine, but when I try to run that app in electron.io, I get only the content of the index.hbs file, which is
 `{{{body}}}`,
as a responce.
In other words: I don't get partials loaded as it should be. Here is the the code from electron file:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
require('./express-app');

 app.on('ready', function() {


var window = new BrowserWindow({minWidth: 1440, minHeight: 900});
window.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/express-app/views/index.hbs');

window.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
    window.show();
    window.focus();
})

window.on('closed', function() {
    window = null;
});
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  app.quit()
})
```

What I would like to know is how to load partials instead of some text or HTML tags inside that `{{{body}}}` element.

Comment: Do you have the contents of the hbs file, or the express-app you are referencing? This doesn't give too much context of what you are doing

Comment: Whole Node.js app (with all partials and everything) is inside express-app folder and it is fully functional when run through browser (localhost), but when I try to run it through electron, I get only text, stated in upper question. It doesn't render partials as it should have to.

Comment: I am going to guess you have a nodejs backend, with express endpoints, and you are trying to use electron to communicate to that as your front end. Is that the case? It sounds like you are using a SPA framework like Angular or something else, but you would have your main process run the parent template and your routes will render the partials